# What data does Esri use to create their US_RoofTop locator?

Tags: arcgis-online, address, geocoding

I'm creating address locators to be published on my local ArcGIS server instance and used by various applications. My server does not have access to the internet so I'm unable to use Esri's online locators.

The "US_RoofTop" locator from Esri's online service is providing me with extremely accurate results in many cases. I was wondering what datasets Esri uses to build this locator?

The locators that I create from TomTom's MultiNet or TIGER/Line aren't nearly as accurate.

Comment: They could tell you, but then they'd have to kill you...

Comment: According to [this page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/data-appliance/3.1/help/basemap/index_Left.htm#CSHID=na_address_locator.htm%23|StartTopic=content%2Fna_address_locator.htm%23|SkinName=agda) it's based on TeleAtlas data.

Comment: And according to [this (more up to date) page](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8b980709e0534bb39784dc42f550d554), it's based on NAVTEQ data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESRI switched from TomTom (Tele Atlas) data to Navteq recently.
They pan out as about equal in testing in the US historically.
A deeper question is where they get their data ; )